# "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error when using Trigger.oldMap during an After trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

My Apex trigger unit tests keep failing during `after insert` operations. Specifically they fail when I try and retrieve the old sObject using `Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id)`. Is there something I am misunderstanding about how the `oldMap` operates? This same logic has worked for me before.

Below is the exception output.

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AccountTrigger: execution of AfterInsert
caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 9, column 1: []
```

Here is the trigger

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {
    string unassignedStr = 'Unassigned';
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    List<String> emails = new List<String>();
    for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        if (Trigger.isBefore && acc.Sales_Rep__c != unassignedStr && acc.Date_of_1st_Contact_PA__c == null) {
            acc.addError('You must set the "Date of 1st Contact" field before assigning yourself an Account');
        } else if (Trigger.isAfter) {
            Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.ID); // Error is thrown here
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                if (acc.Sales_Rep__c != unassignedStr) {
                    System.debug('Contact created with sales rep assigned');
                    accounts.add(acc);
                }
                if (acc.Do_Not_Contact__pc || acc.Replied__pc) {
                    System.debug('Do Not Contact OR Replied flag applied');
                    emails.add(acc.PersonEmail);
                }
            } else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
                if(oldAccount.Sales_Rep__c == unassignedStr && acc.Sales_Rep__c != unassignedStr) {
                    System.debug('Contact updated with newly assigned sales rep');
                    accounts.add(acc);
                }
                if ((!oldAccount.Do_Not_Contact__pc && acc.Do_Not_Contact__pc) || (!oldAccount.Replied__pc &&acc.Replied__pc)) {
                    System.debug('Do Not Contact OR Replied flag applied');
                    emails.add(acc.PersonEmail);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    InfusionSoftClient.CreateContact(accounts);
    InfusionSoftClient.AddTag(emails);
 }
```

Here is the test I am trying to run

```
  private static string salesRep = 'Test Sales Rep';
  @isTest
  private static void TestUpdateAssignSalesRep() {
      Account acc = new Account(FirstName='First',
                                LastName='Last',
                                Sales_Rep__c = 'Unassigned');
      insert acc;

      Test.startTest();
      Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new CalloutMock());
      acc.Sales_Rep__c = salesRep;
      update acc;
      Test.stopTest();

      System.assertEquals(salesRep, acc.Sales_Rep__c);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`after insert` triggers do not have an `oldMap` context variable - it is not meaningful in the context of an insert.

It's very rare to have code that should run the same way on every trigger event, and this is another strong impetus to use a quality trigger framework where all logic is contained in a static method on a testable class. While you have largely broken your logic out into `if` statements, this line

```
Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.ID); // Error is thrown here
```

is not properly isolated in logic guards based upon your trigger event.

Your overall architecture with an outer `for` loop is unlikely to be maintainable and will probably lead to more errors or to issues with bulkification. I strongly recommend removing all code other than `if (Trigger.isInsert)` type logic from your trigger and factoring all "working" code, including iteration over the affected records, into a static handler class.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! Could you recommend a trigger framework for me to implement?

Comment: I don't have the experience with publicly-available ones to recommend one over another, but there are a lot of solid examples available.